# Why is for/while loop variable incrementing by 1 after loop exit? Unwanted side effect

Tags: java

Here is the code -

```
int i = 0;
    
System.out.printf( "\n%d\n\n", i );  // show variable i before loop
    
for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
{
    System.out.printf( "%d\t", i );
}
    
System.out.printf( "\n\n%d\n", i );   // show variable i after loop
```

Here is the output -

> 0
>
> 0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
>
> 8

My problem arises when I want to use the variable i after the exit of the for loop.  I would assume that i is reading 7, the 8th increment in zero based counting but it actually reads as 8!!!  One more increment to variable i has been made on loop exit.

In order to remedy this I would have to do something like i--  at the end of the loop and before using it in any further code.  This seems to me to make the code harder to understand.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Condition fails when `8<8`, which cause loop exit.

Comment: @Mahesh Why didn't you put this in as an answer?  Since that's what it is...

Comment: @ErickRobertson I should have. But answers came up since my comment.

Comment: Always an answer frenzy on this kind of a simple question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `i` is 7, the condition `i < 8` is still fulfilled, so there is no reason to exit the loop.

It is not very clear to declare the loop variable before the loop and use it afterwards anyway. Rather, consider declaring the loop variable with the loop statement.

```
int numIterations = 8;
for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    // ...

}
// continue doing something with numIterations, or numIterations-1
```

If using `numIterations-1` really bothers you, you could also instead use `int maxCounter = 7` and use `i <= maxCounter` instead as loop invariant.

Comment: +1 for declaring `numIterations` separately.  This makes so much sense I could spit.

Comment: @arne.b thank you- this solution makes the code much easier to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
```

the middle part, `i < 8`, is the **loop invariant**: as long as it holds, there will be a next iteration. Therefore once you leave the loop, it is **because the invariant holds no longer** and `i` cannot possibly be less than 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that is easier to read do the following:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 7;
System.out.printf( "\n%d\n\n", start );  

for(int i = start; i <= end; i++ )
{
    System.out.printf( "%d\t", i );
}

System.out.printf( "\n\n%d\n", end );
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop exits when `i == 8`, because the loop condition says: keep iterating as long as `i < 8`. Or to put it another way: stop iterating when `i >= 8`.

So the last `i++` inside the loop will assign `8` to `i`, exiting the loop. That explains the results you're obtaining, and they're as expected. Perhaps you incorrectly assumed that the last `i++` isn't executed before exiting the loop.

To obtain the behavior you want, try this instead - the intent of the code is clearer:

```
int i = 0;
int iterations = 8;
System.out.printf( "\n%d\n\n", i );
while (i < iterations) {
    System.out.printf( "%d\t", i );
    i++;
}
System.out.printf( "\n\n%d\n", --i );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct, otherwise it would never exit because `7 < 8`.

In this code is of course useless to add more logic because you already know that at the end of the loop the variable will always be the same. I think you need it in a more complex code with conditionals statements, so in that case you can do this:

```
int i = 0;

System.out.printf( "\n%d\n\n", i );  // show variable i before loop

for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
{
    if ( i == 3 )  // just for example
        break;
    System.out.printf( "%d\t", i );
}

System.out.printf( "\n\n%d\n", i );   // show variable i after loop
```

and this will print:

```
0

0 1 2 3

3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really simple if you know the order of operation

- STEP_1 - Action before body operation.
- SETP_2 - Evaluate logical expression that continue operation if true.
- STEP_3 - Perform body operation.
- STEP_4 - Action after body operation.

So:

```
for(STEP_1; STEP_2; STEP_4) {
    STEP_3
}
```

Usually in step 1 we initialize our variable and in step 4 we modify it for next evaluation of loop.

```
int i = 0;

for(; i< 8; i++) {

}
```

The loop breaks when `i == 8`, as is declared before loop the value stay.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop the variable i is incremented until it reaches 8 or more at which point the condition triggers leaving the loop.

This is just the way it works.

So you have two options that I can think of.

subtract one from the variable i after the loop.

put an if statement in the loop so that when i equals 7, it does a break.

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  if (i == 7) break;
}
```

Another option would be do use a do while as in:

```
i = -1;
do {
  i++;    // increment i so that it is at the correct current value starting with zero
  // loop stuff
} while (i < 7);
```

Comment: Easier and more clearly is `for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)` as shown above.

Comment: @ott--, when the loop exits, i will still be equal to 8.  And for an experienced programmer it is not more clear and it is certainly not any easier.  Experienced programmers in Java and C and C++ think in terms of zero based and going from zero to one less than the max.  Using less than means you can use array.length and other similar constructs as well.

Comment: You're right, it's 8 after the loop (I should have tested that).